# Checking HDD health

Tags: hard-disk

I have a set of old Seagate SATA HDDs that are part of an LVM on Raid setup in a NetGear ReadyNAS. The ReadyNas no longer boots (it hangs on checking FS). I tried reinstalling the OS which did not fix the problem. One piece of advice I have been given is that one of the drives may have failed and that I should check the drive health with the [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/internal-hard-drives/consumer-electronics/ld25-series/seatools-dos-master/) program that Seagate provides. Despite being called "SeatTools for DOS" and being an ISO image Seagate says it is only compatible with Windows. I don't believe them and my guess is I could create a bootable CD from it, but my question is, is there a set of Linux tools that will do the job for me? What tests should I run to see if a drive is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Disk Utility application on Linux to run the SMART test, which can provide you the health of the HDD.